# Extracting an attribute from top level node of a Feedme XML feed using template

Tags: plugin-feedme

I'm trying to extract an attribute from a top level XML node but having some difficulty.

Given some XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<slots>
  <slot start="Monday" finish="Tuesday">
    <title id="1234">John</title>
  </slot>
  <slot start="Thursday" finish="Friday">
    <title id="5678">Fred</title>
  </slot>
</slots>
```

and some Twig:

```
{% set params = {
        url: 'http://above.xml',
        type: 'xml',
} %}
{% set feed = craft.feedme.feed(params) %}
```

I can extract values and attributes from the inner nodes

```
{{feed.slots.slot.0.title.attributes.id}}
{{feed.slots.slot.0.title}}
```

which yields `1234 John` as I would expect. But now, how do I get the attributes from the slot node e.g. I want the 'Monday'. I've tried something like

```
{{feed.slots.slot.0.attributes.start}}
```

but that just throws an error.

**EDIT:** If I change the XML (remove the inner title nodes) to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<slots>
  <slot start="Monday" finish="Tuesday">
  </slot>
  <slot start="Thursday" finish="Friday">
  </slot>
</slots>
```

then

```
{{feed.slots.slot.0.attributes.start}}
```

works. So maybe the question now is how do I extract attributes from a node that has sub-nodes?

Comment: By using the dump command it seems to me that if a node has sub nodes, its attributes are not loaded into the array (craft.feedme.feed(params)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears now that this is an issue with the plugin being unable to read attributes of a node which has sub-nodes. The developer has noted this, and will hopefully post a fix. In the meantime as work around I used a short php script on the server to call the XML file first and rework the data into a format that the plugin can read.